# what are cokernels in the category of R-modules

Tags: category-theory, modules

The definition of cokernels says that a cokernel $f : Y \rightarrow X$  is a pair $(C; c)$ of an object $C$(a cokernel
object) and a morphism $c : X \rightarrow C $(a cokernel morphism) such that $c$

(1) composes with $f$ to the zero morphism : $c \circ f = 0_{YC}$ and

(2) is a universal such morphism in the sense that any other such morphism $d: X \rightarrow D$ factors through c
as $d = g \circ c$ for some unique morphism $g : C \rightarrow D$.

I understand that C has to be the coker $f =\frac{x}{im(f)}$ but I am not sure what map $c$ should be  and also, how should I define the map $g$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $C$ is given by the quotient $\def\im{\operatorname{im}}X/\im f$, then the only natural map $c:X\to C$ is the projection $X\twoheadrightarrow X/\im f$.
Certainly every $x\in\im f$ will vanish under this map.

Moreover, if $d:X\to D$ vanishes on $\im f$, then the first isomorphism theorem (or what is apparently called the "fundamental theorem on homomorphisms" but in any case) this factors uniquely as $X\twoheadrightarrow X/\im f\to D$.

Comment: Thanks @Shibai . Let's say $\pi : X\rightarrow \frac{X}{im f}$. I understand that $x \in im f $ will vanish under $\pi$, but I am not sure how to write $(\pi \circ f )(x)$ explicitly.

Comment: Since $\pi(x)=0$ for all $x\in\operatorname{im}f$, you would have $(\pi\circ f)(y)=0$ explicitly. Alternatively, write elements of $X/\operatorname{im}f$ as $x\mod\operatorname{im}f$, then $\pi(x) := x\mod\operatorname{im}f$ and $\pi(f(y))=f(y)\equiv 0 \mod\operatorname{im}f$.

Comment: I see. Thanks @Shibai.